# Xcode 10: what is in 'Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/IB Support/Simulator Devices'?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I noticed that this directory:
`/Users/$USER/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/IB Support/Simulator Devices`

contains some rather large directories on my Mac:

```
$ du -d1 -h | sort -h
...
1.7G    ./A7F495BF-B286-4A8B-83A7-7E3D32A237AE
2.4G    ./E9F53010-C7A9-469D-8859-D482D6D334FC
5.9G    ./E85370F1-3126-4679-AA61-35DCAA6B7871
9.8G    ./56FB0674-0DA8-41BA-BA0D-0398CF2139A1
 22G    ./9F55C8ED-15A2-4FF7-8052-BA4464B290F9
 32G    ./3CA6DF23-014A-4939-9B5F-9039655B8D03
```

Digging a little deeper, `3CA6DF23-014A-4939-9B5F-9039655B8D03/data/tmp` contains a lot of *.uicatalog files.

These UUIDs do not show up when I run `xcrun simctl list`.

Does anyone know what creates these files, and if it's safe to delete them?

Answer (score 8):

Xcode creates those files after each build. They are unused, so you can delete them. If it is a server, you can periodically delete them:

Create a file with the library path:

```
sudo vim /etc/periodic.conf.local
```

In it, write:

```
daily_clean_tmps_dirs="/tmp /Users/<user-name>/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/"
```

Run to make sure files are deleted every 3 days:

```
du -sh /Users/<user-name>/Library/Developer/Xcode/UserData/IB\ Support/
sudo periodic daily
```

Answer (score 1):

Best I can give at the moment is a partial answer, as I'm running into a similar issue with our test server. These files are just sqlite databases. When opening them up and viewing their contents, it appears to be lots of metadata related to UI components in your app, and references to assets in the Asset Catalog. I don't know what the purpose of these files is though.

As these things live in a `/tmp/` folder, it's likely safe to delete them. I deleted them all on my server, and so far the tests have continued to run with no issues, and new *.uicatalog files are being created with each test.

Comment: Thanks! 

This post seems to have relevant information about *.uicatalog files; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35793641/whos-creating-the-files-private-var-tmp-untitled-uicatalog